# Angular 2 declarations in specific component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Last time I use Angular2 the directives are still present but now there is so called declarations in app.modules.ts. Question is, if I am going to use a directive only in specific component and not on the main, how can I do that?

customers.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-customers',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/customers.component.html'
})

export class CustomersComponent {
    customers = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mix'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Ian'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Aniel'},
    { id: 4, name: 'Jess'},
    { id: 5, name: 'Jusi'},
    ];
}
```

customer.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-customer',
    templateUrl: 'app/customer/customer.component.html'
})

export class CustomerComponent {
    @Input() customer: {id: number, name: string};

    myColor = 'gray';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customer/customers.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CustomerComponent, CustomersComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What am I thinking is when I put a component in a declaration, every component can access that unlike before that I can only declare it in a specific. Please correct me if I'm wrong here and please suggest if there is a better alternative in declaring directives.

Comment: When you declare it in the module, every other component in the module can use it without having to re-declare it. Why is it a problem if you just simply want to use it in some component?

Comment: From my perspective, it is like asking why do we need to lessen, or stop using global variables? In order to restrict access to only particular function or method right? And it will not messed up if you accidentally access the global variable in the wrong method.

Comment: How about creating a NgModule for your CustomerComponent? Would that fix your needs?

Comment: `Components` are not variable, they are more like class, and there's nothing wrong with having a class definition globally known by all members of a module. Using the component's selector in the template (e.g. `<app-customer>`) is like instantiating new object of that `CustomerComponent` class, and `<app-customer>` in `ListingComponentA` is different than `<app-customer` in `ListingComponentB`, so you can't accidentally access it outside the scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the component declaration into a [Feature Module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules).
The [Feature Module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules) should be imported into the App Module.

Now it's up to you if you consider that your component it's a feature and deserve a separate Module or not.
I'm aware that all this thing with the modules is not so simple and clear as it was with the directives, but there were some design things in Angular2 that couldn't be resolved in other way.

Documentation : https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules

Comment: What happens when 2 feature modules contain a component with the same name now?

Comment: You should never have a component in 2 different modules, if the component is used more than once then it should be in a Shared module : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Comment: pretty disappointed by angular to encourage such a terrible approach - basically it discourages separating functionality or templates into quick sub-components because you always need to also make new modules around - which in the case of using sub-components for simpler purposes (e.g. code structuring and avoiding long files) is just overkill imo

Comment: @tibbus provided link broken. Please update with this [link](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules)