# Restrict a pipe to be used in one component in a module

Tags: angular

In angular 2, I have a pipe that is used in one component and would like to know how to prevent sharing it to other components in same module.

I want to ensure that the scope of my custom pipe is only that component which I want and not to other components in same module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 declarations in specific component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629071/angular-2-declarations-in-specific-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not possible**, the only way to restrict the pipe to one specific component is to use a **separate `ngModule`** for both the pipe and the component.

If you want to use the component above, you should export just the component so that it can be used in another module.

Comment: I believe this would then apply to any custom directives as well.

Comment: yeah to all the providers as well

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Since score restricted pipe is not possible. You can achieve your goal using parametrised pipes. Ex : send a flag to pipe then write conditional code block inside pipe method itself .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

@Component({
  selector: 'power-booster',
  template: 
    `<h2>Power Booster</h2>
    <p>Super power boost: {{2 | exponentialStrength: 10}}</p>`

})
export class PowerBoosterComponent { }

> if nothing works , brief your scenario..